# Spring Boot AOP does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I'm new to Spring Boot and AOP and I've spent the last three days trying to get this to work with no avail.

I have a class called App.  This class invokes a method called invokeRetrieveMethod -- which invokes another method in an autowired businessClass object.  I'm simply trying to log the time it takes to run a method annotated with my custom `@LogExecutionTime` annotation, but I get a null pointer exception when running my code. Please help!

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    @Autowired
    BusinessClass businessClass;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        System.out.println("Starting application...");

        App app = new App();
        app.invokeRetrieveSomething();
    }

    public void invokeRetrieveSomething() {
        businessClass.retrieveSomething();
    }
}
```

The Spring boot "bean"(?)

```
@Component
public class BusinessClass {

    @LogExecutionTime
    public void retrieveSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is the retrieveSomething() method.");
    }
}
```

my Aspect

```
@Aspect //specifies that this is an aspect
@Component //because we want this class to be turned into a bean in order for it to work supposedly
public class ExampleAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); //executed before the method annotated with @LogExecutionTime is executed.

        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

        //everything below gets executed after the method.
        long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + executionTime + "ms");

        return proceed;
    }
}
```

My Custom annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD) //tells us *where* this annotation will be applicable (ElementType.METHOD means on methods only)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) //states whether the annotation will be available to the jvm at runtime or not. by default, it's not.
public @interface LogExecutionTime {

}
```

Comment: Try using fully-qualified class name in the pointcut expression: `@Around("@annotation(fully.qualified.LogExecutionTime)")`

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `App`. You should get the instance from the context and invoke the method on that instance.

Answer (score -1):

Enable the AspectJ in the App class using the annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
Read more at: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html